# Making a true promise "on the dharma"

Tags: lay-buddhism, five-precepts, precept, happiness

Is making a true promise, on the dharma, good karma?

Not asking about the precepts per se, but it was about precept centred behaviour (a lack of infidelity etc. from me): and now I feel blissed out, independent of how it was perceived etc.. Just curious.

Comment: Oh yeah? So, you made a comitment in your mind and then you got all blessed out?

Answer (score 1):

Very good, very good, when in accordance with the Dhamma, and even liberating if kept, good householder. It's like it act-ually works, this way of guided self-blessing and honesty toward one self. And it's not at all bad kamma to break low and harmful earlier promises, for going in contract with more sublime. Such asn for today on, I will abstain from any taking of life, and give up all previous promises requiring such... taking what isn't given... fleshly misconduct... wrong speech... taking intoxicants causing shamelessness...and give up all previous promises requiring such.

mudita

more on it: [Is changing your mind same as lying? Breaking promises](https://forum.sangham.net/index.php?topic=8136.msg12397#msg12397)

Comment: haha. it was a promise about the past, not the future!

Comment: The is no promise not related to the past, good householder. Every promise happened only in the past. "Will promise..." is also already a past one.